# Calling two different controllers from the same button based on a condition

Tags: ios6, storyboard, segue, controllers

I had the following code working before iOS6, but I cannot find an easy way to do it with iOS6, storyboards and Xcode 4.5

```
-(IBAction) ButtonPressed:(id)sender{

    if(condition == 1]) {

        FirstController *firstController = [[FirstController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        firstController.delegate = self;
        firstController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentViewController:firstController animated:NO completion:nil];
        [firstController release];
    }

    SecondController *secondController = [[SecondController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        secondController.delegate = self;
        secondController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentViewController:secondController animated:NO completion:nil];
        [secondController release];

}
```

This used to work fine. If I leave the code as is in iOS6, none of the controllers will show properly. Trying to transition the controller navigation to the storyboard does not help matters either since it appears I can have only one action to trigger a transition using a modal segue from ButtonPressed to either the one or the other. 
Embedding the first controller in the viewdiload of the second controller has its own problems. If it is on the viewdidload will not work properly as other have experienced. If I put it on viewdidappear, the second controller will show up first creating an unpleasing UI. Any ideas?

Comment: one FYI: best practices in Objective C say that you should start your method names with lower case letters.  In other words, change your "`ButtonPressed`" action declaration to "`buttonPressed`".

Comment: Are you missing an else condition here? if condition == 1, are you executing both?

Comment: No, if condition is 1, then it will run first the firstController and then the second. If condition is not one, then it will run the secondController only. The thing I want to do is to upload a file to an internet. If user is not registered, then he has to go through the first controller (registration) and then the second controller (upload). If the user is registered, then it can go to the upload controller directly.

Answer (score 0):

A view controller can only present one view controller at a time. A different approach is required. For example, you can use a navigation view controller for what you wish to accomplish. If the user is logged in, you set the upload view controller as the root view controller of the navigation view controller. If the user is not logged in, you set the root view controller as the login view controller. When the user logs in, the login view controller will notify in its delegate that the user logged in, and you can then push the upload view controller into the navigation stack.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{

    UINavigationController* nvc;

    if(condition == 1) {
        FirstController *firstController = [[FirstController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        firstController.delegate = self;
        firstController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstController];
        [firstController release];
    }
    else {
        SecondController *secondController = [[SecondController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        secondController.delegate = self;
        secondController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondController];
        [secondController release];
    }

    [self presentViewController:nvc animated:YES completion:nil];

    [nvc release];
}

//Login view controller delegate method
- (void)loginViewControllerDidLoginSuccessfully:(FirstController*)loginViewController{
    SecondController *secondController = [[SecondController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    secondController.delegate = self;
    secondController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [secondController.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
    [loginViewController.navigationController pushViewController:secondController animated:YES];
    [secondController release];
}
```